# measurable sets and open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb {R} $ with a positive measure. Then, show that for any positive real number $r $, there is an open interval $I$ such that $\operatorname{m} (A\cap I)>r\cdot \operatorname{m} (A^c\cap I) $, where $\operatorname{m}$ is the usual Lebesgue measure.

I tried to solve it by direct construction, but I couldn't when $A$ is dense in $\mathbb {R} $.

This is my final question today on real analysis.

Comment: You can find, using regularity, an open set $O\supset A$ with $m(A\cap O)>r m(A^C\cap O)$. Write $O$ as a countable union of disjoint open intervals and show at least one of these intervals "works".

Comment: I couldn't find the exact way to use regularity.. thanks!

Comment: Explaining David Mitra's comment: Let $O\supseteq A$ open with $m(O)<m(A)(1+r^{-1})$. Then $m(O\cap A^c)=m(O)-m(A)<r^{-1}m(A)$. Writing $O=\bigcup I_n$, we obtain $\sum m(A\cap I_n)=m(A\cap O)=m(A)>rm(O\cap A^c)=\sum rm(I_n\cap A^c)$, so at least for one $n$, $m(A\cap I_n)>rm(I_n\cap A^c)$.